# Internal microphone issue

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit, microphone

Since flashing 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 onto a rather aged Mac-Book, I've lost the use of the internal (analogue) microphones. I did a search which came up with two suggestions:

- Adding the lines `alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel and options snd-hda-intel model=auto` to the end of the alsa-base.conf file, which didn't work
- Installing pavucontrol, which then showed the gain controls, but still didn't make the microphones work in any of the permutations suggested.

Any ideas?

:) Thanks in advance.

Comment: same here played with alsamixer pavucontrol and system  settings, if i smash the microphone area it registers something but not usable anyway, 16.04 is bad dream

Comment: Can you post some information on the hardware?  The system's model, and the output of `lspci` please.